# Experience to Level Algorithm PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I am developing a Game and I didn't want an array full of levels that would most likely increase page load when iterating through them to find the users Level. I needed an algorithm to work this out independently with only the User's experience to hand. This is because I want the max Level to be around 1,000, and an array that long would take some time to go through.

I have, with some help, come up with the following algorithm for the difference between each level:

```
difference = difference + (difference / 7)
```

And it works well on the lower-levels, but this graph is the Levels 1-141, and as you can see, it's extremely easy up until about half way, then it shoots up and carries on shooting up, until it gets to the point 1,500,000,000 Experience is Level ~250, which isn't good enough.

[image: The Graph for Levels 1-141]

So, my question is, what do you think is a better way to do the difference between each level? Any advice is welcome, I will test all algorithms.

Thanks.

Comment: Voting to reopen, I have no idea why this was closed.  It's a problem that nearly every game programmer *(whose game contains xp-points)* faces.  I **could**, however, see moving it go [gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), where it would probably be closed, not for being off-topic but for being [a duplicate](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18867).

Comment: The question's subject is totally of design character. His problem is how to show the change of difficulties to a player so, that he would feel himself growing enough on all levels. It is solely UI design question. Yes, it should go to gamedev. The fact, that there is already a similar question, only proves that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, there's the linear system.

```
Level = Experience / 1000
```

Every 1,000 experience equates to one level. To make leveling slow down, you decrease the rate at which experience is acquired. This has the added bonus of making super-easy activities count as zero experience later, so you can't become epic by slaying rats.

Then there are decreasing-returns curves of various sorts. For example:

```
Level = (Experience/1000)^(1/scale)
```

With a scale of 2 (sqrt curve), for level 1, you need 1,000 experience. For two, you need four thousand. For three, nine thousand. Each level gets harder and harder. If you make the scale smaller, the rate at which the difficulty ramps up decreases (the slope gets less steep).

I suggest building the function itself, rather than building the first derivative (as you seem to have tried to do). That'll give you a better idea about the graph before you integrate.

Comment: It means "on the n-th power". x^(1/n)=n-th root of x.

Comment: Use Pow(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Comment: The document writes. For Level = (Experience/1000)^(1/scale), use `$level=pow($experience/1000,1/$scale)`

Comment: @ThomasMosey If you want Level 1 to be the first level (instead of Level 0), just add 1 to the formula. If you want to go by tens instead of thousands, just change the denominator to 10.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something that That has a horizontal asymptote at y = 1,000, which grows more quickly for small x than it does for large x. For instance, we might want to solve the system

```
dy/dx = a/x
lim (x->infinity) y = 1,000
```

We get that

```
y = C_0 - a/(x^2)
```

Using the limit, we get that

```
lim (x->infinity) y = C_0
```

So we get the equation

```
level = 1,000 - a/(exp^2)
```

We can make all users start with one experience, or simply change this to

```
level = 1,000 - a/(exp^2 + 1)
```

Either way, users would start out at level

```
level(0) = 1,000 - a
```

So if you want users to start at level 0, let a = 1,000; if users start at level 1, let a = 999. So I might recommend the following:

```
level(0) = 1,000 - 1,000(exp^2 + 1)
```

For experience starting at 0. You can change the rate of convergence by changing the power of exp; higher powers mean faster convergence to the max experience, lower powers mean longer convergence. The power 2 is just a suggestion; any positive real power will be fine.

Note that this is just one approach to constructing such a function. You can integrate any dy/dx which is larger for small x than for large x, and you will get another function that you can parameterize in more or less the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Really, everything depends on how you make a level according to its difficulty. That algorithm could be set so, that the change from 1 to 1.1 will be felt much more, than the change from 1000 to 1000000. Or, on the contrary.

Will the algorythm sensibility to difficulty in different ranges be the same for the same relative change? Or for absolute change? Or for another function of the difficulty and its change? It is for you to decide.

So, the value of difficulty  and strategy of its growth is only a psychological problem.

What I like: make these numbers grow linearly and be small. 1-1000 by 1 is more than enough. You could include some names for different ranges of difficulties, according to the theme of your game.  But of course, you can start at million and go to quadrillions. Again, it is your choose. It is design, not programming or algorithms.